# Divs won't center CSS

Tags: html, css

So, I have a few divs that i want to center. 
I'm currently using this css code on something i call a "container div" - you've most likely heard this "container" thingy before.

```
    #container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Although this does not seem to center the divs when resizing the window; If I resize the window, the divs will follow slowly and by that -move further away from the center.

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kud3f01n/

What is causing the divs to behave like this?

Comment: you issue is not centring but overflow ... the container has a percentage width while the inner elements have pixel width

Comment: Please include your relevant [mcve] code in your question.

Comment: it can't with this structure

Comment: You're not explaining what you want to do as clearly as you might be. As it is right now, your example appears to be working exactly as it is supposed to. As Temani Afif has said, you have set up the width and margins of your internal blocks to be static, so they won't adjust in size as the screen does. What happens then is that they become horizontally scrolling elements. So, instead of simply saying that it "doesn't work" please explain how you want it to work.

Comment: Note, you cannot have multiple elements with the same id. You should use class instead.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you! could you please post an answer so i accept it;)

Answer (score -1):

As verified in your example, I've found that you made those blocks design by using margins(negative and high range values). Hence even you are giving main container width 75% or any other still it will overflow from the parent div. And this kind of CSS will create critical issues in smaller devices.

Suggestion: Try to avoid this type of CSS. And if you need this type alignment and it has t be work in responsive also you can some third party plugins such as masonry.js etc.,

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
#container {
height:50px;
width:50px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```